# saving select 'text' not 'value' when saveRow is executed in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

```
editable:true,edittype: "select",
editoptions: {
    dataUrl : '/test.do?cd=abc', 
    cacheUrlData: true,
    buildSelect : function(data) {
        var data = ($.parseJSON(data)).list;
        var s='<select>';

        for(d of data){
            s += '<option value=' + d.comCd + '>' + d.comNm + '</option>';
        }
        s += '</select>';
        return s;
    },
},
```

When I checked the data after saving,
it contained d.comNm, which is text, not d.comCd, which is the value of the option.

var gridData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData');
console.log(gridData);

It is jqgrid 5.2.1 version, and it is an old project using java 1.7.

Can someone please help me?

[Expected this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrXBY.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlfdB.png)

I have no problem with it appearing on the grid.
The biggest problem is that the value is not stored in the data (getRowData).

Comment: Do you have a formatter : 'select' defined too? Where you save the data - on server or local - i.e what is the **datatype** property or **editurl**? If you have a local datatype then try to get the data property - grid.getGridParam( 'data');

Comment: Hello. editurl is 'clientArray'. formatter: 'select' is not set. This is because when I set it, the "name" comes out, not the "value" of the select. I want to show the "values" in the grid. grid.getGridParam( 'data'); -> results in an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as understand you want to display in grid the value, but when inline edit if on, you display select with value=> text on it, but when saved to save and display the value.

To do this the trick is to define custom formatter only, which return the cellvalue. For that field in colModel do

```
colModel : [
....
{ 
   name: 'name1', 
   editable:true,
   edittype: "select", 
   editoptions : {...}, 
   formatter : function(cellval) { 
      return cellval;
   } 
}
...
]
```